# height being relative to chosen element

Tags: css

Do you know if I can choose the element which should be used to define relative height for other one?

Comment: By default, its parent is used to define relative positions. Tho' I guess you need to position it relative to something else..

Answer (score 1):

The height by default will be relatively defined by its parent. Meaning that a nested div with `height: 100px;` will only ever be as high as the div it is inside of (not accounting for margins/padding).

You can use jQuery to set heights based on other elements.